# MYSQL - Query to get values from one table if the value doesn't exist in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with a query. I need to create a view based on this query.

I've got 3 tables: seller, item, seller_item

Seller table

| name | id |
| --- | --- |
| S1 | 1 |
| S2 | 2 |
| S3 | 3 |

Item table

| name | id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I1 | 1 | 50 |
| I2 | 2 | 100 |

Seller_Item table

| seller_id | item_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 75 |
| 2 | 1 | 25 |

View I'd like to obtain

| nome | item | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | I1 | 75 |
| S1 | I2 | 100 |
| S2 | I1 | 25 |
| S2 | I2 | 100 |
| S3 | I1 | 50 |
| S3 | I2 | 100 |

Basically, if the item is not present in the table seller_item I want to insert the default value coming from the item table otherwise the one from the seller_item table.

I was able to achieve something similar using WHERE NOT EXIST, but only when I ask for a specific seller id, instead, here, I want to have the list of all the sellers with all items.

Thank you.

***----- SOLUTION -----***

Thank you for your quick answers.

Just few minutes after I posted the question I found the solution. It was a lot more verbose than what I was able to find thanks your suggestions.

The final query (with all the values I need) is this one:

```
    SELECT
S.name AS name,
I.name AS item,
IF(SI.visible = 0, SI.visible, I.visible) AS visible,
IF(COALESCE(SI.price, 0) = 0, I.price, SI.price) AS price FROM seller S JOIN item I LEFT JOIN seller_item SI ON S.id = SI.seller_id AND I.id = SI.item_id ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` and `COALESCE` function.
The query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT
    s.name nome, i.name item, COALESCE(si.price, i.price) price
FROM
    Seller s CROSS JOIN Item i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Seller_Item si
    ON s.id=seller_id AND i.id=item_id
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t2WpF5dVbu85PwPk3jdMTG/0)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a corrso join for get all the combination between item and seler and the join the seller:iem  ..
when the join match use the seller price otherwise use the imte price

```
select seller.name
    , item.name
    case when seller_item.item_id  is null then item.price else seller_item.price

from seeler 
cross join item  
left join seller_item on seller_item.item_id = item.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below query is what you are looking for

```
SELECT
 s.name as name,
 i.name as item,
 IFNULL(si.price, i.price) as price
FROM item i
LEFT JOIN seller_item si ON i.id = si.item_id
LEFT JOIN seller s ON s.id = si.seller_id
```